# How does android update activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose, I have the TextView(there is no text), and I also have the Button. After I click this Button, TextView is changed and it will be having text. 
But how does android react to this change, how it will know that I pressed that Button and changed text and TextView must be updated?

Comment: It doesn't. You will have to specify that somehow, e.g. by adding an `OnClickListener` on the button that calls `setText` on the TextView.

Comment: Thanks for answer Michael. :)

Comment: There are more events you can subscribe to (for example: long click). Either read about it in the docs or explore them yourself by writing `button.on`. the Android Studio IDE will give you suggestions